# Unable to get FTP server directory listing from android ftp4j client

Tags: android

Running following code on emulator. Connecting to filezilla server on windows development host using ip address  10.0.2.2.

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
try
{
    ftp.connect("10.0.2.2", 21);
    ftp.login(username, password);
    String REMOTE_DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY = ftp.currentDirectory();
    File mDirectory = new File(REMOTE_DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY);
    File[] listing = mDirectory.listFiles();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Problem: The File[] contains listing of files on android client instead of server.

Thanks
Imdad

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, android doesn't have FTP client library in standard SDK. Which FTP library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same library for my Android project and to get the listing I use the following:

`FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();`

`ftpClient.connect(serverName);`

`ftpClient.login(username, password);`

`ftpClient.setPassive(true);`

`ftpClient.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);`

**`final FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.list();`**

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator dosen't support FTP connection...

Because, Emulator is fixed port to 5554 ~ 5555?

FTP prot is 21..

So, you just run on real device.